# Converting 4/6/2022 into format 04062022 as a string?

Tags: vba

As noted, just trying to take a cell with a pre-populated date - say 4/6/2022 - and convert it into 04062022. I have a series of files that end in the "04062022" format that I have built a macro to open and copy data from, but now I need to make it dynamic such that it pulls from today's date (rather than just 04062022 which is how I have the code setup).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date()` and `Format`:

```
=Format(Date(),"mmddyyyy")
```